# Is there a Numpy pad equivalent which lets you specify desired size?

Tags: numpy

`numpy.pad` wants me to specify the amount of padding, but what if I just want to specify the total desired size in each dimension then have my array symmetrically padded to achieve that?

I'm not looking for someone to write a function for me. Instead, I'd like to know if there's anything that does it out of the box.

Here's an example of how `numpy.pad` would work:

```
>>> arr = np.ones(shape=(4,4))
>>> arr
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
>>> arr = np.pad(arr, [(1,1),(1,1)])
>>> arr
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
>>>
```

And now what I wish I had

```
>>> arr = np.ones(shape=(4,4))
>>> arr
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
>>> arr = np.magic_pad(arr, (6,6))
>>> arr
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
>>>
```

Comment: Why?  Can't you calculate the required parameters yourself.  It shouldn't be too hard, or take too much calculation time.   But since you are just filling the background with 0, you could create the desired result array (`np.zeros((n,n)`) and copy the source into a slice.  It would actually be faster than `pad`.  Do you know that `np.pad` is Python code, not a fast compiled 'black box'.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm asking of the existence of something. If it doesn't exist, I can live with it.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare Did either of the posted solutions work?

Comment: @Divakar they work but don't answer my question. My question was whether an inbuilt function exists. Although I'm quite certain now the answer is no, which is all I needed.

Comment: Yeah, there's none. That's the answer maybe you are looking for.

Comment: Feel free to add that as an elaboration and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare Edited my post with that note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no builtin to achieve that exact functionality. But there are always alternatives. So, here's one with array-assignment -

```
def pad_to_shape(arr, out_shape):
    m,n = out_shape
    x,y = arr.shape
    out = np.zeros(out_shape, dtype=arr.dtype)
    mx,my = (m-x)//2, (n-y)//2
    out[mx:mx+x, my:my+y] = arr
    return out
```

Sample runs -

```
In [76]: arr
Out[76]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])

In [77]: pad_to_shape(arr, (8,6))
Out[77]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

In [78]: pad_to_shape(arr, (4,6))
Out[78]: 
array([[0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in which you can specify the amount of padding you want on each side:

```
# Value to pad by (on both sides)
pad_width_left = 5   # Padding on lefthand side
pad_width_right = 3  # Padding on righthand side

# Now pad vector
arr_padded_left = np.pad(arr, pad_width_left)[:-pad_width_left]
arr_padded_right = np.pad(arr_padded_left, pad_width_right)[pad_width_right:]
```